# How I can get url 'from' and 'to' in ui-router 1.0.0 onBefore?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, transition

As a Title says - is there any way to get urls **from** and **to** from here:

```
$transitions.onBefore({}, function(t){
    //here
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vfZ7WS5V12tPq3SiWfDj?p=info).

With UI-Router we do have access to **from** and **to** state and its **params**. We can then easily use these information with a `stateService` and call `href()` to get from and to url parts

This could be the way:

```
$transitions.onBefore({}, function(t){

  // to state is TargetState
  var toState       = t.to();
  var toStateName   = toState.name;
  var toStateParams = t.params(); // by default "to"

  var fromState       = t.from()
  var fromStateName   = fromState.name;
  var fromStateParams = t.params("from");

  // here we generate the HREF
  var fromHref = t.router.stateService.href(fromStateName, fromStateParams);
  var   toHref = t.router.stateService.href(  toStateName,   toStateParams);


  console.log(fromHref);
  console.log(  toHref);

});
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vfZ7WS5V12tPq3SiWfDj?p=info)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but will $location.url() not do the same thing?